# Render Dynamic MetaTags in ASP.NET Page in Separate Lines

Tags: asp.net, webforms

When i add meta tags dynamically they render in one line.

How can i break them in separate line

[image]

I tried following code but this is not working for me

```
Page.Title = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Title"].ToString() + " by " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Author"].ToString();
Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\n"));
Page.MetaDescription = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Desc"].ToString();
Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\n"));
Page.MetaKeywords = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Keywords"].ToString();
Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\n"));
```

I am using asp.net web forms for my website. Help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: I can render meta tags in separate lines by creating `LiteralControl` and appending all the meta tags to `LiteralControl` using `string builder`.. this would be my second approach if i cant find any solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you try to add the new line will not work because the MetaDescription is all ready exist in a specific location, and you add the new line "somewhere" but not right after.

Try to add all the controls for your header the one after the other as:

```
HtmlMeta metaDes = new HtmlMeta();
metaDes.Name = "description";
metaDes.Content = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Desc"].ToString();

// add the description on the hader.
Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaDes);
// right after add the new line
Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\n"));
```

Or you can even simple add a literal on your header and just render the final output, a set of of your html code.

Answer (score 1):

Its too late to post. But may be helpfull to future readers.

To display `keywords` & `description` meta on **new line** try the following:

```
protected void AddMetaTag()
{
    HtmlMeta description = new HtmlMeta();
    description.Name = "description";
    description.Content ="some desc";

    HtmlMeta keywords = new HtmlMeta();
    keywords.HttpEquiv = "keywords";
    keywords.Name ="site keywords";

    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\r\n"));
    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(keywords);
    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\r\n"));
    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(description);
    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\r\n"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
<meta name="keywords" content="site keywords" />
<meta name="description" content="some desc />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was able to achieve new lines in the meta tags with the following method:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
meta.Append("<meta name=""description"" content=""");
meta.Append(description);
meta.Append("""/>");
meta.Append(Environment.NewLine());

....

Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(sb.ToString()));
```